# Is it enough to implement only ISO-29500 latest revisions to consume almost all XLSX documents properly?

Tags: openxml, xlsx

In part 1 of ISO-29500(2016) there is a section mentioning differences between ECMA 376:2006 and ISO/IEC 29500 but there is no section mentioning the differences between latest ECMA and ISO revisions

References:

- https://www.iso.org/standard/71692.html
- https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm